# ASP .NET + Docker on linux throws system.io.filenotfoundexception: could not find file

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I have an error in my .NET Web Api project when I run it with Docker on linux. This is just a very small email service that I want to host . The file that throws the error is the html email template file, so its a .html file.

My service works in debug mode on windwos and also in docker running on windows, however when I run it on my webserver and try to send an email it throws

> system.io.filenotfoundexception: could not find file

the relative path should be in docker:

/app/Templates/email-template.html

I already search in the internet for a solution but did not found it for myself.
What I tried so far are:

a)
Changing the path in the EmailService.cs file

```
//1st try
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Templates/email-template.html"

//2nd try
@"Templates/email-template.html"

//3rd try
@"templates/email-template.html"

//4th try
@"email-template.html"
```

In the docker file I tried to copy the files to the workdir file because I read that maybe they did not got copied during the docker build

I tried those copy stuffs in the docker files

```
#1
COPY MailService.WebApi/Templates/email-template.html /app/templates/
#2
COPY MailService.WebApi/Templates/email-template.html .
#3
COPY ["MailService.WebApi/Templates/email-template.html", "MailService.WebApi/"]
```

I really don't understand why its not working on linux since it is percefly running on windows (both debug mode and docker).

Comment: try this way `var path = Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase + "/Templates/email-template.html")`

Comment: @coder_b

Thank you! I have tried it, but got a little different error now

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM4USDE9JJF0", Request id "0HM4USDE9JJF0:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/app/file:/app/MailService.WebApi.dll/Templates/email-template.html'. `

Comment: apologies it give you the assembly name with location it runs , so you need strip out the file name, this is much better, `var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory , "Templates/email-template.html")`

Comment: constructed path seems to be correct, why don't you run interactive shell mode and check the files are exists?